# Shell Script File - Pass Multiple Parameters to Interpreter

Tags: linux, shell, python

I have a Python script that I run which needs to execute under a special environment, so I would run the program like so from my working directory (`~/project/src`):

```
python manage.py shell
```

This opens up an interactive shell for me to start typing my own commands.

I have another set of administrative activities that I would like to house in another directory (`~/project/admin`).  The *manage.py* is really finicky about running from the working directory.  So, to make this whole thing work, I made a script which starts off like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python ../src/manage.py shell
```

There are a couple problems with this.  The first is that it doesn't work:

```
/usr/bin/python: can't open file '"/../src/manage.py" shell': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

- How do you specify multiple parameters to the interpreter?
- How do I change the working directory?

Comment: This looks like a Django environment. You may get better responses on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Doug: It started out as Django, but has been magnificently altered at this point.  My only problem now is script-related, so I figured that should go here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only specify one argument to the interpreter. I don't think you can use relative directories in it either.

I would suggest that you wrap what you need to do in a shell script or a Python script that uses Popen() to call it perhaps.

Comment: [It varies depending on the OS.](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#splitting)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I'm correct in my guess that you're in a Django environment...

Take a look at James Bennet's article about [Standalone Django Scripts](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/). Look at the section about "Use setup_environ()" which mentions that this is "exactly how Django’s own manage.py script handles settings".

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847469/use-django-from-python-manage-py-shell-to-python-script) on stackoverflow which will probably help you as well.